# How to JUSTIFY long caption in IEEE Tran template using CAPTION package?

Tags: captions

I face trouble JUSTIFY the alignment of a three-line caption in the following environment. The caption becomes left-aligned.

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{Figure5.png}
\caption{full page 3 line long caption}
\label{Fig_1}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: AFAIK the IEEEtran document class is incompatible to the caption package.

Comment: I was going to add that you should avoid long captions, but 3 lines is not THAT long.  You can add justified text in a figure in addition to a caption.